# gitignore for a python venv based in the root of a git project

Tags: python, git

I'm setting up a python project in git and the I want to run the project in a venv. I'm running `python3 -m venv .` in the root of the git repo.

This creates multiple directories and a file:

- bin
- include
- lib
- lib64
- share
- pyenv.cfg

Which of these files and folders are import to my colleagues to set up the environment in the same way I did? In the root of the project I've also included this script to set up:

```sh
python3 -m venv .
source bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should ignore the entire `venv` folder.

To make that easier, you probabaly want to do `python3 -m venv .venv` instead, and add `.venv` to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! This had the added benefit of vscode picking it up and asking if I wanted to change python interpreter (which my previous approach did not)

Comment: This did not work for me!